# Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in

Tags: php, database, data-binding, code-snippets

I'm working with PHP PDO and I have the following problem:

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in /var/www/site/classes/enterprise.php on line 63
```

Here is my code:

```
    public function getCompaniesByCity(City $city, $options = null) {
  $database = Connection::getConnection();

  if(empty($options)) {
   $statement = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM `empresas` WHERE `empresas`.`cidades_codigo` = ?");
   $statement->bindValue(1, $city->getId());
  }
  else {
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM `empresas`
    INNER JOIN `prods_empresas` ON `prods_empresas`.`empresas_codigo` = `empresas`.`codigo` WHERE ";

   foreach($options as $option) {
    $sql .= '`prods_empresas`.`produtos_codigo` = ? OR ';
   }

   $sql = substr($sql, 0, -4);
   $sql .= ' AND `empresas`.`cidades_codigo` = ?';

   $statement = $database->prepare($sql);

   echo $sql;

   foreach($options as $i => $option) {
    $statement->bindValue($i + 1, $option->getId());
   }

   $statement->bindValue(count($options), $city->getId());
  }

  $statement->execute();

  $objects = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  $companies = array();

  if(!empty($objects)) {
   foreach($objects as $object) {
    $data = array(
     'id' => $object->codigo,
     'name' => $object->nome,
     'link' => $object->link,
     'email' => $object->email,
     'details' => $object->detalhes,
     'logo' => $object->logo
    );

    $enterprise = new Enterprise($data);
    array_push($companies, $enterprise);
   }

   return $companies;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're trying to build a long(?) series of 'or' comparisons: `if (x=1) or (x=2) or (x=3) etc...`. You may find it easier to replace it with:

```
$cnt = count($options);
if ($cnt > 0) {
   $placeholders = str_repeat(', ?', $cnt - 1);
   $sql .= 'WHERE '`prods_empresas`.`produtos_codigo` IN (?' . $placeholders . ')';
}
```

which, if there were 5 options, would give you

```
 WHERE prods_empresas.produtos_condigo IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

And then do the values binding with:

```
$pos = 1;
foreach ($options as $option) {
   $statement->bindValue($pos, $option->getId());
   $pos++
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a mismatch between the amount of bound parameters and the amount of binds in the SQL. Double check that the amount of `?` and the amount of bound parameters is the same.

Additionally, `HY093` will show up if you have tried to bind a parameter that does not exist:

```
$stmt = "INSERT INTO table VALUES (:some_value)";
$stmt->bindValue(':someValue', $someValue, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

See that `:some_value` does not match `:someValue`! The fix is:

```
$stmt = "INSERT INTO table VALUES (:some_value)";
$stmt->bindValue(':some_value', $someValue, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Answer (score 0):

Positional parameters in SQL start at 1.  You're handling this by binding to position `$i+1` in your $options loop.

But then you bind the last parameter for `cidades_codigo` to position `count($options)`, which overwrites the last parameter set in the $options loop.

You need to bind the last parameter to position `count($options)+1`.

---

FWIW, you don't need to `bindValue()` at all.  It's easier to just pass an array of parameters to `execute()`.  Here's how I'd write this function:

```
public function getCompaniesByCity(City $city, $options = null) {
  $database = Connection::getConnection();

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `empresas` WHERE `empresas`.`cidades_codigo` = ?"

  $params = array();
  $params[] = $city->getId();

  if ($options) {
    $sql .= " AND `prods_empresas`.`produtos_codigo` IN (" 
      . join(",", array_fill(1, count($options), "?") . ")";
    foreach ((array)$options as $option) {
      $params[] = $option->getId();
    }
  }

  $statement = $database->prepare($sql);

  echo $sql;

  $statement->execute($params);
  . . .
```

Also be sure to check the return value of `prepare()` and `execute()`, it will be `false` if there's an error, and you need to check for that and report the error.  Or else enable PDO to throw exceptions on error.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this problem due to having extra entries in the named parameter mapping array passed to PDO::Statement->execute()

```
$args=array (":x" => 17 );
$pdo->prepare("insert into foo (x) values (:x)");
$pdo->execute($args); // success
$args[':irrelevant']=23;
$pdo->execute($args) // throws exception with HY093
```

Comment: I dont understand if this is an answer or a just a comment on the OP.  Could you rephrase please?

Answer (score -2):

Since you have made `$i+1` in the loop so `count($options)` would equal the last `$i+1` which makes a duplicate binding.Try

```
 foreach($options as $i => $option)
 { 
      $statement->bindValue($i + 1, $option->getId()); 
 }

 $statement->bindValue(count($options)+1, $city->getId());
```