# SQL error when submitting a form in a redirecting page

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713566/warning-pdostatementexecute-sqlstatehy093-invalid-parameter-number-num)

I try to submit a ad form with different options of ad kind but when I submit the form that gives this error:

> Error : SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound
>   variables does not match number of tokens

SQL code:

```
try
{
$pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '', $pdo_options);
$req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO ads (kind, kind2, kindsale, titre, price, money, country, state, county, city, adress, phone, message, image, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, inputid, date, ldesc, email, account, room, area, uarea, file, mark, miles, mi) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
$req->execute(array($_POST['kind'], $_POST['kind2'], $_POST['kindsale'], $_POST['titre'], $_POST['price'], $_POST['money'], $_POST['country'], $_POST['state'], $_POST['county'], $_POST['city'], $_POST['adress'], $_POST['phone'], $_POST['message'], '1'.$name.$name6.$_FILES['image']['name'], '2'.$name2.$name5.$_FILES['image2']['name'], '3'.$name3.$name4.$_FILES['image3']['name'], '4'.$name4.$name3.$_FILES['image4']['name'], '5'.$name5.$name2.$_FILES['image5']['name'], '6'.$name6.$name.$_FILES['image6']['name'], $_POST['inputid'], $_POST['date'], $_POST['ldesc'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['taccount'], $_POST['room'], $_POST['area'], $_POST['uarea'].$name3.$name4.$_FILES['file']['name'], $_POST['mark'], $_POST['mileage'], $_POST['mi']));
header('Location: index.php');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    die('Error: '.$e->getMessage());
}
```

Some data in the form are hid with $('.thing').hide(); in jquery but I think even hid these are submitted as void so exist.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Oh no no no .. try to catch up your design called *[database normalisation](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm)*, your table `ads` is screaming for it. Second your error has to do with not enough parameters (or too many) being bound against the number of questions marks `?` or placeholders in the query. Just count them and see where one or two (or more) are missing (or too many)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, my parameters have same numbers, what you mean by catch up the design ?

Comment: As Vincent Ramdhanie alread pointed out, you have 32 question marks (as in placeholders), but you bind only 30 parameters, so 2 question marks can't be bound to a value

Comment: Oh thanks sorry, you solved a part of my problem but now it's written: SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: Have you googled for SQLSTATE[21S01]? It's a lot faster then waiting for an answer here. It means exactly as it says, the `ads ( kind, kind2, ..etc )` line should match the columns in table `ads` in your database. Most of the time this error means you have to many columns in your `(kind, kind2, .. etc)` query, for example look for an empty quote like `(kind,,kind2)`,

Answer (score 0):

The number of parameters you provided is lessthan the number of parameters in the SQL Statement. That is you have 32 question marks in the SQL statement and that means that you have to provide 32 values. If my count is correct you only provided 30.

Comment: You actually count them? :P, forget the (at) :D

Comment: @dbf Had to see, couldn't help myself.