# Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens on line 38

Tags: php, authentication, system

I am working on a login and register system and I am getting this error whenever I try to register a new account.

> **Warning: PDOStatement::execute():** SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in /home/public_html/classes/DB.php on line 38

Line 38 is `if($this->_query->execute()) {`.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); 

class DB {
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo, 
        $_query, 
        $_error = false, 
        $_results, 
        $_count = 0;

    private function __construct() {
        try {
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));                                          
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    } 

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {
            self::$_instance = new DB();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
        $this->_error = false;
        if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
            $x = 1; 
            if(count($params)) {
                foreach($params as $param) {
                    $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                    $x++;
                }   
            }
            if($this->_query->execute()){
                $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
            } else {
                $this->_error = true;
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function action($action, $table, $where = array()) {
        if(count($where) === 3){
            $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');

            $field          = $where[0];
            $operator       = $where[1];
            $value          = $where[2];


            if(in_array($operator, $operators)) {
                $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";
                if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) { 
                    return $this;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function get($table, $where) {
        return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);
    }

    public function delete($table, $where) {
        return $this->action('DELETE', $table, $where);
    }

    public function insert($table, $fields = array()) {
            $keys = array_keys($fields);
            $values = null;
            $x = 1;

            foreach($fields as $field) {
                $values .= '?';
                if($x < count($fields)) {
                    $values .= '. ';
                $x++;
            }

            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (`" . implode('`, `', $keys) . "`) VALUES ({$values})";

            if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }   

    public function update($table, $id, $fields) {
        $set = '';
        $x = 1;

        foreach($fields as $name => $value){
            $set .= "{$name} = ?";
            if($x < count($fields)) {
                $set .= ', ';
            }
            $x++;

        }

        $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$set} WHERE id = {$id}";

        if($this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function results() {
        return $this->_results;
    }

    public function error() {
        return $this->_error;
    }
    public function count() {
        return $this->_count;


    }
}
```

**User.php**

```
<?php
class User {
    private $_db,
            $_data,
            $_sessionName,
            $_isLoggedIn;

    public function __construct($user = null) {
        $this->_db = DB::getInstance();

        $this->_sessionName = Config::get('session/session_name');

        if(!$user) {
            if(Session::exists($this->_sessionName)) {
                $user = Session::get($this->_sessionName);

                    if($this->find($user)) {
                        $this->_isLoggedIn = true;
                    } else {
                        // process Logout
                    }   
                }
            } else {
                $this->find($user);
        }   
    }

    public function create($fields = array()) {
        if(!$this->_db->insert('users', $fields)) {
            throw new Exception('There was a problem creating an account.');
        }
    }

    public function find($user = null) {
        if($user) {
            $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'username';
            $data = $this->_db->get('users', array($fields, '=', $user));

            if($date->count()) {
                $this->_data = $date->first();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    public function login($username = null, $password = null) {
        $user = $this->find($username);

        if($user) {
            if($this->data()->password === Hash::make($password, $this->data()->salt)) {
                Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);
                return true;
            }   
        }

            return false;

    }

    public function logout() {
        Session::delete($this->_sessionName);
    }

    public function data() {
        return $this->_data;
    }

    public function isLoggedIn() {
        return $this->_isLoggedIn;
    }
}
```

**Register.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

if(Input::exists()) {
    if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {
    $validate = new Validate();
    $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
        'username' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 2,
            'max' => 20,
            'unique' => 'users'
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 6
        ),
        'password_again' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'matches' => 'password'
        ),
        'name' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 2,
            'max' => 50
        )   
    ));

        if($validation->passed()) {
            $user = new User();

            $salt = Hash::salt(32);

            try {

                $user ->create(array(
                    'username' => input::get('username'),
                    'password' => hash::make(input::get('password'), $salt),
                    'salt' => $salt,
                    'name' => input::get('name'),
                    'joined' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                    'group' => 1
                ));

                Session::flash('home', 'you have been registered and can now log in!');
                Redirect::to('index.php');

            } catch(Exception $e) {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
                echo $error, '<br>';
            }
        }
    }   
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="field">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value"<?php echo escape(Input::get('username')); ?>" autocomplete="off">
        </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label for="password">Choose a password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label for="password_again">Enter your password again</label>
        <input type="password" name="password_again" id="password_again">
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label for="name">Enter your name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" value"<?php echo escape(Input::get('username')); ?>" id="name">
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

Comment: You shouldn't do `die($e->getMessage())` in your constructor. It will display your login credentials if you fail to connect for whatever reason.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713566/warning-pdostatementexecute-sqlstatehy093-invalid-parameter-number-num

Comment: You should also let us know what your SQL is and what parameters are being passed to the query() method.

Comment: @Mike Although I am no longer getting that error, I am still receiving an error saying the account can not be created "There was a problem creating an account."

Comment: You still haven't posted your actual SQL query. How do you expect people to debug your code when you post 200+ lines of logic and don't even give the result it produces?

Comment: @Mike updated and edited

Comment: @user3291224 All you have done is post another file, but you haven't provided your actual query. This just makes it even more difficult to debug. What is the actual SQL query that is failing, and what does MySQL say?

Comment: @Mike The actual error says. "There was a problem creating an account."

Answer (score 0):

When building your query in the `insert()` method, I believe the line `$values .= '. ';` needs to instead be `$values .= ', ';`

This should cause the prepared statement to be formatted correctly.

Comment: So the error is now gone, but now I am getting the error, "There was a problem creating an account."

Comment: Check to make sure no error was returned by mysql, and see that no record was actually created in the database.  If you are still having trouble, post the code that outputs that error message.

Comment: I added Users.php to the main post and that is what displays the error

Comment: To debug this, you should examine what your `$sql` string looks like, and check for any error messages attached to the last query that was executed.  In this case, I think you have a trailing `,` at the end of your `VALUES(?,?,?,?,)` string.  To fix this, set `$x = 0;` instead of `$x = 1;` in the `insert()` method.

Comment: I changed that line, but unfortunately I am still getting the unable to make an account error.

Comment: So since the query is failing, what is the error message returned from  mysql?

Comment: How would I find this error since it appears I am not posting the right one

Comment: From the look of the code, try `$this->_db->error()`

Comment: and where exactly should I put that line?