# <b>Warning</b>: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in

Tags: php, mysql

I have encountered this warning while updating data to the database here is my code

```
function update(){ 
    // update query
    $query = "UPDATE
                " . $this->table_name . "
            SET name = :name, episodedate = :episodedate, episodenumber = : episodenumber, streamlink = :streamlink, 
            seasonid = :seasonid
            WHERE
             id = :id";

    // prepare query statement
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    // sanitize  
    $this->seasonid=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->seasonid));
    $this->name=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->name));
    $this->episodedate=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->episodedate));
    $this->episodenumber=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->episodenumber));
    $this->streamlink=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->streamlink));
    $this->id=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->id));

    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $this->name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':episodedate', $this->episodedate);
    $stmt->bindParam(':episodenumber', $this->episodenumber);
    $stmt->bindParam(':streamlink', $this->streamlink);
    $stmt->bindParam(':seasonid', $this->seasonid);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $this->id);

    // execute the query
    if($stmt->execute()){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Please any body can help me. I have checked all typos , table structure , query but all in vain please help me.

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. We can’t run your screenshot as code.

Comment: Also, as you've probably realized, the title cannot have HTML tags in it.

Comment: You have a space after `:` (`: episodenumber` should be `:episodenumber`) in the query.

Comment: @tadman But if you try and edit those HTMl tags out of the title you get a warning about another question having that exact title already (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713566/warning-pdostatementexecute-sqlstatehy093-invalid-parameter-number-num?rq=1)

Comment: When using `bindParam`, which is the way to safely supply user data to a query, **DO NOT** use `htmlspecialchars` or `strip_tags` on input. Those should be used if and when the content is pulled from the database and displayed in an HTML context. Your database should contain raw values as you may need to encode those for JSON/JavaScript or plain-text in which case you do not want HTML encoding at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be binding the episode id to `:id` rather than to `:episodeid`
you are also binding the episode name to `:name` rather than `:epiname`
try replacing 
`$stmt->bindParam(':id', $this->id)` with `$stmt->bindParam(':episodeid', $this->id)`
and
`$stmt->bindParam(':name', $this->name)` with `$stmt->bindParam(':epiname', $this->name)`
You also have a space between the `:` and `episodenumber` in `$query`

Comment: Isn't it great when the op changes things on the fly?

Comment: Thanks man space was the issue. and i have spent more the three hours debugging. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query = "UPDATE
          " . $this->table_name . "
          SET name = :name, episodedate = :episodedate, episodenumber = :episodenumber, streamlink = :streamlink, 
          seasonid = :seasonid
          WHERE
          id = :id";
```

//copy and paste this code.